# published npm package is not visible npm

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-publish

I'm new to npm, recently I published an npm package 'mango-aliyan' and I can see it at https://www.npmjs.com/~shakkirptb, but https://www.npmjs.com/package/mango-aliyan is showing 404!

what am I missing here?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had a similar issue recently and I believe NPM does not immediately publish packages. There could be a number of reasons and I'm sure it's done on purpose.

If you wait about 5-10 minutes your package will be publically visible. I have visited the link to your package and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: yay,its visible now. :)